# Unable to debug Whitelisted device / ApplicationSession failing to start

Tags: android, google-cast

I am not able to connect to my Whitelisted Chromecast through the given address (ip.address:9222) as mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver#debugging

When attempting to test my Android sender implementation, my app can successfully see and select the Chromecast device via [MediaRouteActionProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteActionProvider.html) I receive [SessionError](https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/android/javadoc/reference/com/google/cast/SessionError) code CODE_REQUEST_FAILED in CATEGORY_CONNECT_CHANNEL immediately.

I've included my app id in both the Sender and Receiver.  I've verified the Chromecast was in [discovery state](https://developers.google.com/cast/design_consider#receiver-display-in-discovery-state) when attempting.  I'm able to view the debug info through the Chromecast app on Android to see the device details, but I don't see anything that would confirm the device has been whitelisted.  Is there a particular key that would verify the device is whitelisted?  Am I missing another step?

Comment: I had a similar issue and realized that my device was not getting whitelisted because of a feature that was not selected in my Chromecast setup options: "Send this Chromecast's serial number to Google when checking for updates". I'm not sure if you have done the same, but after selecting that option and rebooting, my Chromecast's debugger was accessible right away.

Comment: @methai If you return to that setting screen, is that box still checked? I can't get the box to stay checked.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty, the Android app has a bug where this setting doesn't save.  See my answer below.  Thank to methai for putting me on the right track.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty - I was having the same issue until i clicked "Done" to save my settings to the device before i clicked the reboot button that is on the same dialog. Once i did that i was able to get the setting to stick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to tick the "Send this Chromecast's serial number to Google when checking for updates" box and then "Reboot Chromecast".  (Thanks, methai).

The issue was that there is a bug in the Android Chromecast app (in version 1.1.1), where this setting doesn't actually get saved.  I can confirm the OS X client will save this setting properly, haven't tested the other versions yet.

Comment: I check the box and reboot, but the box is still unchecked and debugging still doesn't work. I can ping the cast though. I've tried a few hard reboots too.

Comment: @thantos, are you using the OS X Chromecast app or the Android app to change the setting and reboot?  The Android app has a bug that causes it not to save the setting.

Comment: Ahh, the reboot doesn't work on the android app then. I mis-read it. Thanks @PrplRudby. I submitted a report, hopefully it gets fixed, really want to play with this api.

Comment: There's a windows app as well. Just go to http://www.google.com/chromecast/setup and download the configuration application for windows, osx, etc. From the desktop app you can configure your chromecast device.

Comment: I was able to set the option by performing a factory reset of my chromecast via the android app and then when I re-configured it via my browser I checked the "Send this Chromecast's serial number..." option.

I'm running linux so that was really my only option.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. I spent an hour trying to figure out why my AppID wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your HTTP server will respond correctly to POST requests for your receiver URL as well as that same URL with '/whatever_you_pass_to_ApplicationSession.startSession' which was an issue with our Rails server.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a combination of checking "Send this Chromecast's serial number to Google when checking for updates" and registering the Chromecast Device, as described here: 
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration

After registering your device, you'll have to wait up to 15 minutes and restart your Chromecast. You'll see this if the status of the device changed in to "Ready for Testing."