# Custom receiver application doesn't work with whitelisted device

Tags: google-cast

I'm just starting to play with Google Cast, so I downloaded the hellotext Chrome example app. If I open the sender that comes with it, everything works. However, if I take the receiver.html file, upload a copy of my own somewhere, create an app, and then replace the app id in the sender.html, it doesn't work.

The console log says "receiver list empty". I do have my Chromecast (both of them actually) added to my account as test devices. I reset them, both via software and by unplugging and replugging them. I even did a factory reset on one of them, but still no luck.

Googling got me to this response: [How to launch a receiver app in Chrome once Chromecast device has been whitelisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911932/how-to-launch-a-receiver-app-in-chrome-once-chromecast-device-has-been-whitelist)

However, the option to enable (or disable) sending the serial number on update check doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I'll end up doing that, but this shouldn't be necessary according to all I've read.

Comment: (@RobertRowntree: there is no need to publish the app.)

Nacho: Make sure you have entered the serial numbers correctly; I recommend you take a picture and zoom in to make sure there is no confusion about 0 vs O, etc. Once you have done that step, power cycle your chromecast.

Comment: @AliNaddaf I double checked the Chromecast serial number, and it's correct. The only confusing letter is a zero, but the voice that reads it clearly says zero.

Comment: I suggest you contact our support at https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1 to get further assistance regarding this issue.